# How can I change object in json file in javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-directive

I am developing a simple app for contacts in angularjs, one view for all contacts (list) and another view when user click on edit .

I have this json.file :

```
{
   "contacts": [
      {
         "id": "1",
         "first_name": "Moran",
         "last_name": "potkin",
         "phone": "0543433543"
      },
      {
         "id": "2",
         "first_name": "Sharon",
         "last_name": "Hadad",
         "phone": "0543655345"
      },
      {
         "id": "3",
         "first_name": "Lior",
         "last_name": "Nimrod",
         "phone": "0543677653"
      },
      {
         "id": "4",
         "first_name": "Yarden",
         "last_name": "Shem",
         "phone": "0523422675"
      },
      {
         "id": "5",
         "first_name": "Mor",
         "last_name": "Dor",
         "phone": "0507244356"
      }
   ]
}
```

And this code in the factory:

```
 var dataCache = {},
            defer = $q.defer(),
            contactsPromise = defer.promise;

        /**
         * Fetch posts data
         */

        $http.get('data/contacts').success(function (data, status) {
            dataCache.contacts = data.contacts;
            defer.resolve(dataCache);
        }).error(function (data, status) {
            $log.error(status, data);
        });

 return {

 set: function(person , id){
                var defer = $q.defer();

                contactsPromise.then(function (data) {
                    var existingPost = false;

                    $.each(data.contacts, function (inx, contact) {
                        if (contact.id == id) {
                            existingPost = true;
                            contact.first_name = person.first_name;
                            contact.last_name = person.last_name;
                            contact.phone = person.phone;

                            defer.resolve(contact);

                            // Stop the loop
                            return false;
                        }
                    });

                    if (!existingPost) {
                        defer.reject(id);
                    }
                });

                return defer.promise;

            }
     }
```

When user clicks on Submit , the set function in the factory gets called.

It does not modify my local json. How can it be modified?

Comment: You need server-side code.  And you should use a database.

Comment: It isn't local. You got it from an HTTP request. You would need to send it to the server and then write to some server side code to modify it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update the json.file you need to *serve* your json data. You could use:

## jsonBlob:

With well [documented functionality](https://jsonblob.com/api), you can write angular to use jsonBlob API. I added your json data to a test jsonblob [located here](http://jsonblob.com/56c12bb2e4b01190df4f02c6)

### GET

Note upon successfully storing/updating the JSON blob, a 201 response will be returned.

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'http://jsonblob.com/api/jsonBlob/56c12bb2e4b01190df4f02c6'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
   console.log(response);
  }, function errorCallback(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

### POST

```
var req = {
 method: 'POST',
 url: 'http://jsonblob.com/api/jsonBlob/56c12bb2e4b01190df4f02c6',
 headers: {
   'Content-Type':
 },
 data: { contacts.id: '12' } ect....

}
```